# Permissions are not translating between windows and linux

Tags: linux, permissions, windows, nfs

So I have an NFS mount which is provided by netapp. It is mounted from a client perspective on both linux and windows machines. If i create a file on the windows mount point then when i look at the permissions on linux the owner/group is "nobody" rather than my AD user.

I read that I should be configuring idmapd.conf on linux to have the domain and to use nsswitch. So i have configured idmapd.conf like so:

```
[General]

Verbosity = 0
Pipefs-Directory = /run/rpc_pipefs
# set your own domain here, if id differs from FQDN minus hostname
Domain = domain.ad.company.com

[Mapping]

Nobody-User = nobody
Nobody-Group = nogroup

[Translation]

Method = nsswitch
```

Other than this configuration. Is there anything else i might be missing? I keep seeing parts about matching UID and GID's, but why would I need to do that if i access both windows and linux via one active directory account?